# Spring Oauth2.0 Missing grant type

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring Oauth 2.O.

When I pass request as a form-data it works fine, but when I try to pass data in `application/json` format it gives me error missing grant type.

**Request**

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth/token

{"username":"parths","password":"123456","grant_type":"password"}
```

**Error I getting.**

```
{
  "status": "0",
  "message": "Missing grant type"
}
```

Please Guide.

Answer (score 32):

**`OAuth2`** doesn't support `JSON` in the access token request.You can check [here for description](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3)..It requires **`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`**

Answer (score -1):

Additionally to Prasanna Kumar I want to add that you need to send your data in body of **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** type like KEY-VALUE
Grant types you can check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/core/AuthorizationGrantType.html#:%7E:text=The%20OAuth%202.0%20Authorization%20Framework,for%20defining%20additional%20grant%20types.)