# Spring security OAuth2 request as object instead of query parameters

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I want to customise OAuth Endpoint URI's. 
I want to sent parameters in post body instead of query params.

now my request is like -

```
example.com/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}&username={USERNAME}&password={PASSWORD}
```

But I want it like this.

example.com/oauth/token

Request body -

```
{
    grant_type=password,
    client_id={CLIENT_ID},
    client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET},
    username={USERNAME},
    password={PASSWORD}
}
```

How should I do it?

Comment: The whole point of OAuth is that the verbs and URL patterns are standardised... What is your usecase for using a POST instead of a GET?

Comment: just for making it more secure. I don't want to expose my parameter values in url.

Comment: You should always use HTTPS. **If not, both GET and POST parameters are sent in plain text** over the wire and neither are secure. I suggest using HTTPS and sticking with the standards.

Comment: I know that. My concern is not about Request type. I don't want to expose my username, password and other parameters in URL. Hence I want OAuth  to accept it as application/json body.

Comment: OAuth doesn't work for `application/json`...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366281/spring-oauth2-0-missing-grant-type/39369071#39369071

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Oauth2.0 Missing grant type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366281/spring-oauth2-0-missing-grant-type)

Answer (score 2):

The token endpoint of a properly-implemented authorization server does NOT accept GET requests because RFC 6749, "[3.2. Token Endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2)" says as follows:

> The client **MUST use the HTTP "POST"** method when making access token requests.

So, your authorization server's token endpoint should reject GET requests.

RFC 6749, "[4.3. Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)" says that request parameters of a token request using Resource Owner Password Credentials flow should be embedded in the request body in the format of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". The following is an excerpt from "[4.3.2. Access Token Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2)".

```
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=A3ddj3w
```

Therefore, **you don't have to customize your authorization server**. If the server is implemented correctly, its token endpoint accepts POST requests.

Answer (score 2):

The token endpoint created by spring-oauth2 already deals with POST as well.
It would be hard to customize it to accept a JSON request body, because the TokenEndpoint class expects all the params as @RequestParam params.

However, if your concern is about security (as HTTPs does not secure query parameters) you indeed can send the request parameters through post. It is just a matter of sending the request in the form "form-data" or "x-www-form-urlencoded". These are 2 ways of sending arbitrary key-value parameters in the request body, in a way that appears to the server as they are regular request parameters. So it is a matter of making your client using this.

Also, note that in spring-oauth2 it is possible to disable the GET endpoint, this way forcing your clients to use POST with one of the ways above.